# Risks to set permissions 777

Tags: files

I set permissions 777 to **/www/sites/default/files** folder and all subfolders. I did this because Drupal 7 would not let me save content. Drupal said me: *The specified file temporary: //filetXbwF7 could not be copied, because the destination directory is not configured correctly*.

Originally, these folders have the permission 755. But that did not work.

What risks are there to set permissions 777?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Some things you should check:

- Check if the owner of the `sites/default/files` is the proper user and groups. The user and group usually is `www-data`, but it depends on your webserver.
- Since you mention temporary folder, you should check if the temporary directory at `admin/config/media/file-system` section of administrator interface is configured properly.

> What risks are there to set permissions 777?

It is a *very* ***very*** bad practice. There are tons of materials on the net you can look at, but long story short: Setting the permission to `777` means that anyone can write *and* execute anything in that folder, including malicious codes.

Comment: There is a very nice bit of documentation on this on Drupal.org [Securing file permissions and ownership](https://www.drupal.org/node/244924)

Comment: @Cerilla, suppose the owner www-data is not proper on my server. So how do I know which is the right owner?

Comment: @Cerilla, the field temporary directory (admin/config/media/file-system) says: /tmp. But in Filezilla I do not see the tmp folder!